# Android WebView html5 video tag with https source

Tags: android, html, android-webview

I have a WebView based application where I want to display a video which is inside a video tag like this:

`<video src="https://video.mp4" controls="controls" type="video/mp4"></video>`

I want to display the video inline (not fullscreen) and like the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) says I  have hardware acceleration turned on, and set a WebChromeClient.

The thing is when I replace the url from **https** to **http** it works and I can see the video correctly, but ***doesn't work with https.***

Is https supported by the media player? Any thoughts on this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting a `WebViewClient`

```
myWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
@Override
public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler,
        SslError error) {
      handler.proceed();
    super.onReceivedSslError(view, handler, error);
}
```

Comment: You were right, there was an issue with my ssl certificate, thanks!