# html5 video tag displays blank screen with only sound

Tags: android, video, html5-video, android-webview

i have created webview and updated `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` in order to run embedded video tag but; only sound is running without video

```
    mWebview = findViewById(R.id.webView);
    mWebview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mChromeClient = new MyChromeClient(this);
    mWebview.setWebChromeClient(mChromeClient);
    mWebview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebview.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);

    mWebview.getSettings().setPluginState(WebSettings.PluginState.ON);
    mWebview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);

    mWebview.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
    mWebview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    mWebview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    mWebview.getSettings().setSavePassword(false);
    mWebview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    mWebview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
    mWebview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
    mWebview.getSettings().setNeedInitialFocus(false);
    mWebview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    mWebview.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(WebSettings.LayoutAlgorithm.NORMAL);
    mWebview.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    CookieManager.getInstance().setAcceptCookie(true);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 17) {
        mWebview.getSettings().setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
    }
    mWebview.setLayerType(1, null);
    mWebview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebviewClient());
    String myvar = "";

    String head = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, user-scalable=yes\" /></head>";

    String summary = "<style>table{ height:100%;}td.height{height:100%;}</style><table width=100% height=100%> <tr><td class=\"height\" style=\"text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;\"><video id='my-video' poster=\"\" controls autoplay style=\"width: 300px; height: 250px;vertical-align: middle;\"><source src='http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4' type='video/mp4' /></video></td></tr></table><script>var myvideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]; myvideo.play()</script>";

    String html = head + "<body style='background-color:#000000;'>" + summary + "</body></html>";
    mWebview.loadData(html, "text/html", null);
```

**adb** log:

> 

```
09/16 22:39:14: Launching app
$ adb install-multiple -r -t -p com.example.ad.myapplication F:\new\MyApplication\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk 
Split APKs installed
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.ad.myapplication/com.example.ad.myapplication.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Client not ready yet..Waiting for process to come online
Connected to process 3426 on device emulator-5554
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
D/MediaResourceGetter: no ethernet/wifi connection detected
W/MediaResourceGetter: non-file URI can't be read due to unsuitable network conditions
E/MediaResourceGetter: Unable to configure metadata extractor
[ 09-16 22:39:18.039  3426: 3478 D/         ]
HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa0f9b0b0, tid 3478
D/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
```

**permissions** :

> 

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Please advice how to display video with sound not only sound i tried all my known solutions 
Thx in advance

Comment: No one could help !!!!!!!

Comment: You could paste the adb output, there should be something relevant to this issue.

Comment: adb logs added ...

Comment: Well, a quick search for the errors you pasted led to this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27876749/android-webview-not-allowed-to-load-local-video-file . So check your permissions and everything. Of course, this does not explain why the audio played. I looked a the video file and it is trivial with h264 baseline. If you are running on simulator, maybe there is no h/w accelerated decoder?

Comment: @RudolfsBundulis I too suspected the H264 profile, but "baseline" works everywhere so I'm stumped how it decodes the audio part but not picture...

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

Comment: Are you running this on an emulator or an actual device?

Comment: I have tested on emulator, bluestack and device

Comment: Plz if u have running sample, share it

Answer (score 0):

> *"How to display video together with sound, not just sound only..."*

Don't use percentages for width/height. Use real numbers.

Test this setup and see if it displays a picture with sound:

```
String myvar = "";

String head = "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, user-scalable=yes\" /></head>";

String summary = "<video id='my-video' controls autoplay><source src='http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4' width='300' height='250' type='video/mp4' /></video>";

String html = head + "<body style='background-color:#000000;'>" + summary + "</body><script>var myvideo = document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0]; myvideo.play()</script></html>";

mWebview.loadData(html, "text/html", null);
```

Also note: `<script>` happens after `<body>` since the script needs that video element to exist first.

Comment: not working same thing only sound, please could u share running copy because i have tested alot of open sources like VideoEnabledWebview

Comment: I'm not near an Android compiler to test your code so can't share fixed code. Do you have `android:hardwareAccelerated="true"` added inside your **Activity manifest file**?

Comment: Also see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23279597/2057709. It might help your situation.

Comment: thx for advice but, added before as mentioned before in original post <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:hardwareAccelerated="true"

Comment: I don't think it's necessary yet but to share full code either use [`Edit`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52348612/edit) or use a site like https://pastebin.com... What version of Android is being tested with? If Oreo, try running on some older OS device.

Comment: I have tested on api 27 and 21